# How to check correct answer from multiple radiobutton taking into consideration answer must be taken from database

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, radio-button

Code:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * from question WHERE question_id='10'" ;
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {

        while (reader.Read()) ;

        label1.Text = reader["question"].ToString();
        radioButton1.Text = reader["option1"].ToString();
        radioButton2.Text = reader["option2"].ToString();
        radioButton3.Text = reader["option3"].ToString();
        radioButton4.Text = reader["option4"].ToString();
    }
}
```

I want to check right answer from these radiobuttons, i have a column in my database
which hold  the value for correct answer for each set of question, how can i fetch it, I'm new in these languages.

Comment: Well, there are two steps here: first, you must fetch the valid values from the database; and second, you must set the radio buttons' captions to those values. Would you like help with both of these steps, or just one? If you'd like help with the first step, we'll need to know the schema of the table in which the possible answers are stored.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend using `while (reader.Read())` in this situation because you need to wait for them to answer, I'm assume. You'd need to run something on the OnChange event of the radio buttons or a button OnClick event (like submit answer) which reads in the next questions and options.

But to read the answer in, it's as simple as reading the options in. Assuming there is a column in your MySql database called `answer`, you fetch it just like the other ones: `reader["answer"].ToString();`.

Comment: Tnx for your help,but what if i'm dealing with just one form,what I wanted is that when the user click next button, the system will check for the corresponding correct answer which is taken from database,and when the answer is correct it will prompt message and also it will call for another set of question in just one form,can you please give me the syntax on how to do that in C#,Thank you

Comment: I would create an instance variable of your data reader type so you can access it across multiple events, and only read the next question on certain events. So, you start the program, fill the reader, access the first row in the query, and fill the radio buttons. The reader will have the answer in it inherently, and how to check it depends on the way your DB is setup. Is it what index the correct answer is, or is it the actual answer? Either way, you should be able to determine if an answer is correct. If the answer is correct, then the event hook should read the next row.

Comment: can you please give me the syntax on how will create an instance for my data reader,in my database i have created a table named question which contains question_id,topic,option1 option2,option3,option4 and key which holds the correct value for each set of questions